# When do the solutions to the linear system $Ax=b$ form a vector subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> When do the solutions to the linear system $Ax=b$ form a vector subspace?
>
> A) If and only if $A$ is invertible;
>   B) if and only if $b=0$;
>   C) if and only if $A$ is not invertible;
>   D) if and only if $b\ne0$.

Is the answer b? As homogeneous solution are closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Welcome to our community! Would be nice if you want to get value from the members that you invest a minimum... Editing the question rather than posting an image, describing what you think...

Comment: You can see that other users have transcribed the text from the picture you posted. There is still long way to go in order to make this [a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), but it is definitely a start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, almost. The catch that doesn't make the b alternative entirely correct is that if $A$ is not a square matrix then the solutions does not need to be in $\mathbb R^n$. Otherwise it's true:

If $b\ne 0$ you will not have $0$ in the set of solutions which is required in a vector space. If $b=0$ on the other hand you will have that $cx+y$ are solutions to if $x$ and $y$ are solutions.

The other alternatives either prohibits $b=0$ or at least is not equivalent to it.